# ¿Cómo hacer una petición POST con Spring Boot y Angular?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

Estoy intentando hacer una petición POST a un API REST hecho con Spring Boot, pero me está resultado imposible. He probado desde PostMan, y obtengo respuesta, pero al hacer la llamada desde Angular no funciona y no se por qué. He estado buscando por internet y no consigo encontrar una solución, no se si es que estoy fallando en algo obvio y no me doy cuenta, pero me resulta imposible. Lo mismo me pasa con las peticiones PUT.

Este es el código que tengo para llamar a la petición del servidor:

```
  check(){
    this.texto = "Texto prueba";
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/check", this.texto);
  }
```

Con el PUT había probado a ponerlo tal que así:

```
  check(){
    this.texto = "Texto prueba";
    return this.http.put("http://localhost:8080/check", this.texto, {});
  }
```

Y esta es la parte del servidor:

```
    @PostMapping("/check")
    public void saveUser(@RequestBody String texto) {
        System.out.println(texto);
    }
```

Comment: Te estás suscribiendo a las peticiones con `subscribe()`?

Comment: No, he visto en muchos sitios que no lo ponen, tan solo hago un ```System.out.println``` para comprobar que se llama a la petición correctamente. De todas formas, si fuera por el subscribe, cómo debería ponerlo?

Comment: El `subscribe()` es en Angular. Las peticiones devuelven un observable y si no hay nada suscrito a el entonces la petición no se envía.  Sería algo así `this.http.put("http://localhost:8080/check", this.texto, {}).subscribe()`

Comment: Vale... Era exactamente eso... Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Agrégale un subscribe al final y puedes hacer algo con la respuesta usando la función de callback.

```
check() {
    this.texto = "Texto prueba";
    return this.http.put("http://localhost:8080/check", this.texto, {}).subscribe(res => {

// Aqui puedes hacer algo con la respuesta, que es res, o el nombre que     quieras. 

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema debe estar con el Intercambio de Recursos de Origen Cruzado (CORS), te recomiendo que a cada método de tu controlador le coloques la anotación @CrossOrigin, para que permitas todos los orígenes:

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping("/check")
public void saveUser(@RequestBody String texto) {
  System.out.println(texto);
}
```

O lo puedes hacer más seguro especificando el origen de donde proviene la petición:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://tu-dominio.com")
@PostMapping("/check")
public void saveUser(@RequestBody String texto) {
  System.out.println(texto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como comentan por aquí, podría ser un problema de CORS, pero eso lo verías facilmente en la consola del navegador.

El problema esta en que cuando haces una llamada desde angular, has de suscrbirte a dicha llamara para que esta llegue a tu back con Spring Boot.

```
check(){
this.texto = "Texto prueba";
return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/check", this.texto).subscribe(() =>     {
  console.log("LLamada al post realizada correctamente");
});
```

}